# getIntent() method is undefined for type ParseApplication

Tags: android, android-intent, import, push-notification, parse-platform

I am making an android application that allows push notifications through parse.com.
It is not recognizing getIntent() as a method of the import android.content.Intent
Here is the line of code I am using it in:

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

and it gives me this error message:

```
getIntent() method is undefined for type ParseApplication
```

These are my imports:

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.PushService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Intent.FilterComparison;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import android.app.Application;
```

I am not sure if I need more imports or if I am doing something else wrong, but please help.
By the way, the push notifications work without that line of code, but the line is for analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParseApplication` should to be of type `Activity` for you to call `getIntent()` the way you want. Importing the `android.content.Intent` won't help in this case. Moreover, `getIntent()` is not an available method prototype for `Intent` class.

The method is referenced here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()

Comment: How do I make `ParseApplication` of type `Activity`, do I need to do `ParseApplication extends Activity`? I already have `ParseApplicaiton extends Application` which I believe would take the place of `Activity`

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just needed to put it in a different class.

Comment: Yes, by extending `Activity` instead of `Application`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html has the class overview, with the blue marked paragraph giving an option you can go with.

Answer (score 0):

In which class you are trying to call getIntent()?
Application class isn't familiar with it. only Activity class

if you have the context of the activity you can always try:

```
((Activity)mContext).getIntent()
```

but be sure to know what you're doing before doing it